# How to disable info logging for ClickHouse JDBC

Tags: clickhouse

Whenever I connect to ClickHouse with JDBC, I get this on my output:

```
ru.yandex.clickhouse.ClickHouseDriver connect
INFO: Creating connection
```

How to disable it?

Answer (score 2):

You can disable or set another logging level for ru.yandex.clickhouse package.
Logging in clickhouse-jdbc is done through slf4j.

For example if you use log4j, you can do like this:

```
<log4j:configuration>
    <!--other log4j configs-->
    <logger name="ru.yandex.clickhouse">
        <level value="WARN"/>
    </logger>
    <!--other log4j configs-->
</log4j:configuration>
```

Precise configuration depends on your exact logging config, but it must be similar.

Answer (score 1):

I met problems in performance of Clickchouse JDBC because of Apache Http Client logger, when [testing](https://github.com/egorlitvinenko/testparsing), this helps me:

```
log4j.configuration=log4j.properties 
log4j.rootLogger=ERROR, stdout
log4j.appender.stdout=org.apache.log4j.ConsoleAppender
log4j.appender.stdout.layout=org.apache.log4j.PatternLayout
log4j.appender.stdout.layout.ConversionPattern=%5p [%c] %m%n
log4j.logger.org.apache.http=ERROR
```

Comment: You can try https://github.com/blynkkk/clickhouse4j as well. It doesn't have Apache Http Client.

Comment: As I understand, it was not an option in the moment of the question. But now yes, could be considered, thank you.