# Disable SQL logging in Clickhouse client

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, clickhouse

I need to disable SQL logging for [Clickhouse client](https://github.com/ilyabreev/ClickHouse.Net) to console. I cannot see anywhere in code where logging is enabled. It just logs by default and its really annoying.

client initialization

```
services.AddSingleton<IClickHouseClientFactory, ClickHouseClientFactory>();
```

example command that dumps text to console

```
var res = _clickHouseDatabase.ExecuteSelectCommand("SELECT max(timestamp) FROM organic_trades");
```

this is what is logs to console

```
info: ClickHouse.Net.ClickHouseQueryLogger[0]
      Clickhouse query: SELECT max(timestamp) FROM mm_latoken_trades completed in 72 ms.
```

Please suggest where can I turn logging off

Comment: Would this be of any help - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46258052/how-to-disable-info-logging-for-clickhouse-jdbc

Answer (score 1):

Well looking at the source on GitHub

```
> ExecuteSelectCommand
```

calls Execute which has this definition: https://github.com/ilyabreev/ClickHouse.Net/blob/67f656098422dd0e6c311972dbcafafcee01703e/src/ClickHouse.Net/ClickHouseDatabase.cs#L290

Which specifically has this line :

```
_queryLogger?.AfterQuery(commandText);
```

The implementation of _queryLogger is here: https://github.com/ilyabreev/ClickHouse.Net/blob/67f656098422dd0e6c311972dbcafafcee01703e/src/ClickHouse.Net/ClickHouseQueryLogger.cs#L6

I can't see any configuration toggles in the code to skip logging.

I guess you could call the *ClickHouseDatabase* constructor, passing in a null *IClickHouseQueryLogger*

```
  public ClickHouseDatabase(
        ClickHouseConnectionSettings connectionSettings,
        IClickHouseCommandFormatter commandFormatter, 
        IClickHouseConnectionFactory connectionFactory,
        IClickHouseQueryLogger queryLogger,
        IPropertyBinder propertyBinder)
    {
        _connectionSettings = connectionSettings;
        _commandFormatter = commandFormatter;
        _connectionFactory = connectionFactory;
        _queryLogger = queryLogger;
        _propertyBinder = propertyBinder;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It needs to high the [severity of the logging](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/logging/?view=aspnetcore-5.0#configure-logging) for *ClickHouse.Net.ClickHouseQueryLogger* in *appsettings.json*-file:

```json
{
  "Logging": {
    "LogLevel": {
      "Default": "Information",
      "Microsoft": "Warning",
      "Microsoft.Hosting.Lifetime": "Information",
      "ClickHouse.Net.ClickHouseQueryLogger": "Warning"
    }  
  },
  "AllowedHosts": "*"
}
```

Comment: changed to Error or None this makes no effect on logging

Comment: could you provide your appsettings.json?